# Area Code not set, caused by programatically creating shipment

Tags: magento2, cli, area

While creating a module, the following error occurs after creating a custom cli command:

```
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.
```

I have already stated the area code in the execute() method of the command class, but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Sync command:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Sync extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     **/
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Action\Action
     **/
    public $action;


    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Action\Action $action,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state

    ) {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->state = $state;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('vendor:module:sync')
            ->setDescription('Syncs with FTP server');
        parent::configure();
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_CRONTAB); //have tried every area (adminhtml, frontend, global)
        $this->action->Connect();
    }
}
```

Action class:

```
<?php

Namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Action;

class Action {

    protected $article;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Shipment\Create\ShipmentCreator $shipmentCreator
    ) {
        $this->shipmentCreator = $shipmentCreator;
    }

    public function Connect() {
    }
}
```

The error is arises when I add my shipment code in the constructor of the action class. Without the shipment code in the Action constructor everything works accordingly.

ShipmentCreator:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Shipment\Create;

class ShipmentCreator extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\OrderFactory $convertOrderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->orderConverter = $convertOrderFactory->create();
        $this->transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->shipmentSender = $shipmentSender;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Create Shipment Based on Order Object
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function generateShipment($orderId)
    {
        try {
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            if (!$order->getId()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The order no longer exists.'));
            }

            /* check shipment exist for order or not */
            if ($order->canShip()) {
                // Initialize the order shipment object
                $shipment = $this->orderConverter->toShipment($order);
                foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
                    // Check if order item has qty to ship or is order is virtual
                    if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
                    // Create shipment item with qty
                    $shipmentItem = $this->orderConverter->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
                    // Add shipment item to shipment
                    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
                }
                // Register shipment
                $shipment->register();

                $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

                try {
                    $transaction = $this->transactionFactory->create()->addObject($shipment)
                        ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                        ->save();
                    echo $shipmentId = $shipment->getIncrementId();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t generate shipment.'));
                }

                if ($shipment) {
                    try {
                        $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t send the shipment right now.'));
                    }
                }

                return $shipmentId;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Are you guys able to reproduce the error and help me find a solution? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed with the help of this answer!

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200004/65919

Changing `shipmentNotifier` to `shipmentNotifierFactory` and then instantiating the class with `shipmentCreatorFactory->create()` fixed the `Area is not set` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `\Magento\Framework\App\State` to your command and use `setAreaCode` to set the areacode.

Use one of the values from `\Magento\Framework\App\Area` to do this.

Comment: Already did this! If you look at the first code snippet I shared, the state object is injected and the execute() method sets the area code.